# Magento 2: how to get the hamburger menu @medias screen 1024px

Tags: magento2, css, rwd

The current hamburger menu is shown @media screen 792px. How do I change it to 1024px?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about CSS media queries and would get more response on a general forum like stackoverflow

Comment: Maby properly should be 768px then do you want 1024px ?